# Passing value between slick

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

I need to make a swipe over the first slick carousel change the second slick carousel through the `onAfterChange` event.

```
<slick  slides-to-scroll="1" arrows="false" current-index="slick.current"  class="first-slide"  next="slick.current" on-after-change="slick.onAfterChange(this)">
    <div>blah blah</div>
    <div>blah blah</div>
<slick>

<slick  slides-to-scroll="{{numtoslide}}" ng-transclude arrows="false" variable-width="true" init-onload=true center-padding="60px" center-mode="false">
    <div ng-repeat="t in fevt track by $index" ng-if="t.section != 'venues'"style="width:320px;margin-right:5px;">
        <a ng-href="#!/about/{{t._event_id}}&all"><img  style="height:160px;width:320px;" class="img-thumbnail" ng-src="{{t.thumbnail}}"/>
        <div class="fc_desc">
            <h3>{{t.headline}}</h3>
            <span class="date-text">{{t.date_string}}</span>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</slick>
```

Comment: could you be more specific?  some code would help :)

Comment: I am using angular-slick. Swipe over first slick carousel changes the second slick carousel using onAfterChange event.

But when it does second carousel will not work

Any help appreciated